# Attention with ConvD1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model

My supervisor asked me to implement an Attention-layer for a CNN (applied on text), but Im pretty sure it does not work for ConvD1-layers.

Using `Keras` I have a pretty straightforward model, with an embedding-layer followed by a convolutional layer.

Since the input for `ConvD1` is `(#documents, words, embedding_size)` followed by a MaxPooling-Layer, I considered dropping max-pool and inserting Attention here, but I really dont know whats my query and value-input in this case.

I know tf.backend has an Attention-Layer, but is it possible to apply it here? Or do I need some kind of self-attention?

What I need, is to see which "words" are (most) responsible for the according classification.

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

conv1 = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2, padding='same')(embedded_sequences)
conv1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=32)(conv1)
conv1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv1)

x = Dense(50, activation="relu",
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
          bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(conv1)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(x)  
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=[TruePositives(name='true_positives'),
                       TrueNegatives(name='true_negatives'),
                       FalseNegatives(name='false_negatives'),
                       FalsePositives(name='false_positives'),
                       ])
```

Comment: I think that you need a simple custom self-attention